# Class 'ArrayList' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'List' - Error with ktor and exposed

Tags: kotlin, serialization, jvm, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying to get started with ktor and exposed and I created this file that just retrieves films from a postgresql db but I can't seem to make it work. Everytime I call the endpoint I get

```
Class 'ArrayList' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'List'.
To be registered automatically, class 'ArrayList' has to be '@Serializable', and the base class 'List' has to be sealed and '@Serializable'.
Alternatively, register the serializer for 'ArrayList' explicitly in a corresponding SerializersModule.
```

---

This is how my file looks:

```
package routes

import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.Entity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.EntityClass
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.IntIdTable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.javatime.datetime
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction

class Film(id: EntityID<Int>) : Entity<Int>(id) {
    companion object : EntityClass<Int, Film>(Films)
    var name     by Films.name
    var director by Films.director
    var createTime by Films.createTime
    var updateTime by Films.updateTime
}

object Films : IntIdTable()
{
    val name = varchar("name", 100)
    val director = varchar("director", 100)
    val createTime = datetime("create_time")
    val updateTime = datetime("update_time")
}

fun Route.listOrdersRoute() {
    get("/films") {
        try {
            val film = transaction {
                addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
                Films.selectAll().toList()
            }
            call.respond(film)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.localizedMessage)
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is how my build.gradle.kts looks:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.21"
    application
}

group = "com.kivin"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:0.40.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:0.40.1")

    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0")

    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.0")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.7")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-test-host:2.3.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-java-time:0.41.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:0.40.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.8.21")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0")


    runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:0.40.1")

    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```

I applied other solutions I found to similar problems in Stackoverflow but they don't fix mine. I tried adding @Serializable tag but it doesn't fix it either and it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the following code returns an object of the `List<ResultRow>` type:

```
transaction {
    addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
    Films.selectAll().toList()
}
```

The `ResultRow` class isn't serializable, and so is the `List`. You must map that list to the list of serializable objects to solve your problem.